# Cannot resolve the hiding of the top menu in bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I use a plugin as html editor in a bootstrap application and it has the following structure for it's dropdown menus:

```
<div class="btn-group" title="Fonts" style="cursor: pointer;">
    <a class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-sm btn-success" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Fonts">Font<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Sans serif</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Serif</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Wide</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Narrow</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Comic Sans MS</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Courier New</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Garamond</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Georgia</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Tahoma</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Trebuchet MS</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="javascript:void(0)">Verdana</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After selecting one of the fonts in the dropdown menu the top "Fonts" button disappears. The reason is that the event bubbles up to the btn-group and set it style element to "display: none".

I have tried to prevent the bubbling up so that only the dropdown menu disappears but the Fonts dropdown can be used again.

I have tried different options, i.e.:

```
$("dropdown-menu li a").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

and a few others but no success.

Any suggestions please?

P.S. I have read all I could find on this subject (including the many examples on here) and spend many hours trying to get it resolved. Furthermore, I tried my best to formulate it as clear as possible, therefore it is a proper stated and researched question.

Comment: Is the HTML for the dropdown menu being created dynamically?

Comment: Yes, it is in the plugins' javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Since the HTML is being generated dynamically, you could use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). The following code you are using

```
$(".dropdown-menu li a").click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

binds a click event to elements matching the selector `.dropdown-menu li a` *when that code is ran*. Since the elements are created dynamically (after this code is run), the event handlers aren't getting attached. By using event delegation, you could write

```
$(document).on("click", ".dropdown-menu li a", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

which will bind the event handler to the document element, *which does exist at the time the code runs*. And this handler will only be fired if an element matching the selector `.dropdown-menu li a` is clicked.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I still get the same result.

Comment: I used the stopPropagation in the ready function and after I ran the rendering code, therefore the elements already exist at the time when the code is run. But your explanation did provide me with something to remember in the future.

Comment: @jmarais Well in that case I don't know the answer. Hopefully someone else will!